# Express.js vhost subdomain set up

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, vhosts

Trying to set up connect's vhost middleware. Would love some help.

I've got my normal express.js app, with node_modules, public, views and routes directories. I've added another directory next to those which holds another express.js app.

I've added this line to my top level app (tedxgramercy):

```
app.use(express.vhost('chatter.tedxgramercy.com', require('./chatter/app.js').app));
```

And this line to my chatter app:

```
var app = exports.app = express();
```

The chatter app calls listen on port 8000, the main (top level) app calls listen on port 3000. I don't know if that's right.

When I launch my app (node app) it runs fine and I can access both apps on localhost:3000 and localhost:8000 respectively, but when I deploy to my server, the subdomain http://chatter.tedxgramercy.com doesn't work.

Any pointers? Do I have to change my DNS to point to the other port or something?

Comment: The hostname in the URL needs to exactly match the hostname in your code (unless you use a glob pattern), so try doing `vhost('chatter.tedxgramercy.com')` or `vhost('chatter.*')`.

Comment: I did, but had no luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a simple, but somewhat tricky setup.

First, the main `app.js`:

```
var vhost = require('vhost');

app.use(vhost('chatter.tedxgramercy.com', require('./chatter/app').app))
app.use(router);
```

I included the router to make it clear that it is critical for it to be used *after* configuring virtual hosts.

Then, in `chatter/app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.use(router);

exports.app = app;
```

This is the bare minimum setup to render a Jade template in a sub app. Notice that app is exported, but no server is actually started since the main app is the server.

Comment: Error: Most middleware (like vhost) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

Comment: Need a clarification : why use router in chatter/app.js ? `app.get('/')` also working same

Comment: @prasanth so as to have separate set of routes that works only for `chatter.tedxgramercy.com`. if you dont pass in the route in `chatter/app.js `  `chatter.tedxgramercy.com`. would be exactly the same as `tedxgramercy.com`